# localhost/phpmyadmin can't access when setting virtualhost

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, xampp, virtualhost

Here is the situation :

I have a project which I want to run on localhost as http://www.coye.com/ for which I have setup a virtual host which is running perfectly like this:

**F:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf :**

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "F:/xampp/htdocs"
ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "F:/xampp/htdocs/coye"
ServerName coye.com
ServerAlias www.coye.com
RewriteEngine on

#Added New by Sandeep - Start
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.coye\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.coye.com$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/images
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/css
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/js
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/fckeditor
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/securityimage
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sitemap.txt
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /index.php?request=$1 [PT,QSA,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

**C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\host**

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 coye.com 
127.0.0.1 www.coye.com 
127.0.0.1 api.coye.com 
127.0.0.1 merchant.coye.com 
127.0.0.1 admin.coye.com
```

and now I want to run `PHPMyadmim` but it not accessible through `localhost/phpmyadmin`.
What changes I have to do to get access PHPMyadmin ? Please guide me on this.

Please help me on this.

Comment: This may be helpful http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#setup

Comment: @EternalHour I have setup a virtualhost and this creating a problem in accessing phpmyadmin. Without virtualhost I can access phpmyadmin

Comment: More than likely you need to configure the config.inc.php properly.

Comment: @EternalHour can you please elaborate this more?

Comment: http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html

Comment: @EternalHour bro I have told you that PHPAdmin is configured correclty and I can run my phpmyadmin when virtualhost is not setuped

Comment: Obviously it's not setup correctly or it would be working.

Comment: @EternalHour did you know something about virtualhost?

Comment: Yes I am familiar with them, are you sure you don't have an alias in your config.inc.php pointing to the wrong location? It's my understanding that all aliases need to be removed.

Comment: Maybe your apache rules are also interfering.

Comment: @EternalHour see my edit I have added a content of config.inc.php file

Comment: Do you have the pmadb configured?

Comment: @EternalHour sorry but I am not aware of this can you pleas etell me this in details

Comment: Also, I believe in `httpd-vhosts.conf` it should be `DocumentRoot "F:/xampp/htdocs"`

Comment: Comment out everything under `/* Advanced phpMyAdmin features */` if you are not using pmadb

Comment: @EternalHour by commenting out those still not wroking

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Finally I found the solution for my problems, hope this will help to others you will face the similar problem :

I have to add this extra piece of code:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "F:/xampp/htdocs"
ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

So the final file will be -

httpd-vhosts.conf :

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "F:/xampp/htdocs"
ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "F:/xampp/htdocs/coye"
ServerName coye.com
ServerAlias www.coye.com
RewriteEngine on

#Added New by Sandeep - Start
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.coye\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.coye.com$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/images
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/css
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/js
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/fckeditor
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/securityimage
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sitemap.txt
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /index.php?request=$1 [PT,QSA,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

host file :

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 coye.com 
127.0.0.1 www.coye.com 
127.0.0.1 api.coye.com 
127.0.0.1 merchant.coye.com 
127.0.0.1 admin.coye.com
```

Thanks to everyone who try to help me.

Answer (score 1):

See you have to keep the original config in hosts file

**127.0.0.1 localhost**

and to access phpmyadmin you need to go to **phpmyadmin.local** and not to 
**localhost/phpmyadmin**

Virtualhost Config

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/usr/local/zend/apache2/htdocs/l2/public"
    ServerName coye.com
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    DocumentRoot ""
    ServerName **phpmyadmin.dev**
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

let me know if it works.

Comment: can you please edit your answer and tell me what changes I have to do in host and httpd-vhost.conf file

Comment: I want to run my project coye using www.coye.com on local thats why I setup a virtual host. From your code I will not able to run www.coye.com

Answer (score 0):

Modify your host file as following:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 coye.com
```

then map your "subdomains" (including www) in your apache files and you should be fine

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
  DocumentRoot "F:/xampp/htdocs"
  ServerName coye.com
  ServerAlias subdomain.coye.com
</VirtualHost>
```

The hosts file in windows works as a domain redirector, not a full name redirector, all your subdomains including www.domain.com must pe aliased in apache virtual hosts.